# Ĉu estas klarigoj de la proverboj el la Proverbaro Esperanta?

Tags: meaning

La Proverbaro tre plaĉas al mi, tamen ne ĉiam mi komprenas la signifon. Ĉu estas **libro** aŭ **retejo** kie mi povus trovi klarigojn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bedaŭrinde ne! La retejo de Rob Keetlaer enhavas ĉiujn, sed ankoraŭ ne inkludas tradukojn nek klarigojn.

Malgraŭ manko de la origina manuskripto, Petro Desmet' kompletigis oklingvan version en 2009, kaj per tio oni povus kompreni la proverbojn pli facile: sed ĝi ankoraŭ ne aperas. Li uzis la pli fruan *Frazeologion*, kiu estas tre malofta libro.

Answer (score 0):

En miaj artikoloj en Ipernity estas dekoj da klarigaj artikoloj. La oklingva proverbaro baldaŭ (vere!) aperos. Ĝi estas nun prespretigita.  Poste aperos klariga listo.

Comment: Ĉu vi povas meti ligilon al viaj artikoloj?

Comment: Simple iru al Ipernity kaj al Petro Desmet kaj vi trovos ilin. Mi tutsimple ne scias kiel fari... krom eble se vi skribas al petrokjoko@gmail.com Tie mi scias kiel fari.

Comment: Ĉu http://www.ipernity.com/blog/petro_desmet ? Kiuj el ĉiuj artikoloj temas pri proverboj?

Comment: http://m.ipernity.com/#/blog/30525/4635838 Bv sciigi ĉu vi ricevis
http://m.ipernity.com/#/blog/30525/4635838 Strange, sed ŝajne ne funkcias